# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Iam using jquery hacker list plugin.

I have created the list by manually, Then it was working. But

Here, I have creating list items automatically, that time im getting error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined
```

Hacker list code is

```
var options = {
        //item: 'hacker-item',
        values: ['name']
    };

    var hackerList = new List('hacker-list', options);
```

I called this code is on ready event.. Somehow i find the issues is. list is created dynamicaaly but list is initialized in ready event. So this is the problem.

How can rectify this?. It is not plugin issue. Pure jquery issue. ready event called before list creating..

Comment: could you provide more of the script as this snippet provides very little information.

Comment: I have using that script and plugin script. Thats it.

Answer (score 1):

since there's no `values` property defined by the plugin, hence you get the error, its `valueNames` not `values`, as per the plugin docs, so change to:

```
var options = {        
    valueNames: ['name']
};
var hackerList = new List('hacker-list', options);
```

Answer (score 0):

In documentation init process looks like this

```
var options = {
    valueNames: ['name']
};

var hackerList = new List('hacker-list', options);
```

Comment: ['name', 'city'] are search values. Now im using name field only